# Login Data - decrypt chrome credentials

Tags: google-chrome, python-3.x

I was trying to decrypt chrome passwords stored in Login Data. I followed by this tutorial:
http://raidersec.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html

Here's my code in python:

```
from os import getenv
import sqlite3
import win32crypt

# Connect to the Database
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Login Data")
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Get the results
cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')
for result in cursor.fetchall():
# Decrypt the Password
    password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2], None, None, None, 0)[1]
    if password:
        print ('Site: ' + result[0])
        print ('Username: ' + result[1])
        print ('Password: ' + password.strip().decode('utf-8'))
```

Login Data file comes from my one OS (Windows 7) and I was trying to decode this file on another system with the same OS (Windows 7).
I read that to decode Login data on another OS it's needed to have the same Windows credentials (login/password), so I changed my Windows login and password, but I got the following error:

```
pywintypes.error: (-2146893813, 'CryptProtectData', 'Key not valid for use in specified state.')
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like Google Chrome would encrypt passwords more securely other than using win32 Cryptography API. That's just my opinion and the `pywintypes.error: (-2146893813, 'CryptProtectData', 'Key not valid for use in specified state.')` to me, means that the win32crypt doesn't recognize the data. There are most likely multiple decryption processes involved to actually acquire a password.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to decrypt a Login data that belongs to a different user.

I used this same code and it worked when I ran it from the same user, that is because Chrome uses the user name in order to encrypt.

If you want your user name type (cmd): `echo %username%`. Or, in Unix `username`

Please let me know if you managed decrypting other users Login data (I'm trying already a few hours to figure it out).